# JS setTimeout stack

Tags: javascript, settimeout

why does setTimeout not work? And how to do this action properly? I need to get 30s delay every submit. Sorry for newbie question, but i am newbie.

```js
 if (event.target.id.indexOf('submit') === 0) 
{ post1000.submit(); setTimeout('post1001.submit();', 30000); }
{ post1001.submit(); setTimeout('post1002.submit();', 60000); }
...
{ post5092.submit(); setTimeout('post5093.submit();', 122790000); }

}, false);
```

Comment: and how to do this action properly? i need to get 30s delay every submit.

Comment: you are trying to set timeout for submit function? Your code already has syntax error,please explain your purpose.

Comment: Please show real, actual code.  What you are showing now makes no sense.  It's like you are executing 5000 submits and then setting a bunch of timers and wondering why all 5000 submits just went.  Also, your `if` statement looks like it is only aligned with the first submit based on the bracing.  Please show real code.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, `setTimeout()` works just fine.  The question is what is wrong with your code, not what's wrong with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: And, do you really have 5000 separate variables named with digits in them like `post1000`?   Please put them in an array instead of uniquely named variables to make this a ton easier.  I won't even attempt a solution with 5000 uniquely named variables.  I wouldn't dare copy/paste that much code or use `eval()` to try to work around it.  Put them all in an array and then show more of your code.

Comment: just added full script

Comment: Your newbie question could've been answered by reading one of hundreds of online tutorials...  -1

Comment: i tried to find the answer.. thanks for solution! when i tryied to do 5 submits everything works fine, but when 5000, delay doesn't work

Comment: When you submit a form with `post1000.submit()`, that reloads the page with the result from the server, and all scripts on the current page stop running. So your `setTimeout()` has no effect because the page has been reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouln't use a string as first parameter for setTimeout();
Here is this function definition :

```
setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)
```

Try with this code sample, or update yours accordingly :

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Comment: That isn't the main issue here.  While passing a string to `setTimeout()` is a bit of an anti-pattern, it does work in many cases.

Comment: Like that?
setTimeout(post1000.submit(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
setTimeout(post1001.submit(){ alert("Hello"); }, 6000);
setTimeout(post1002.submit(){ alert("Hello"); }, 9000);
...
setTimeout(post5000.submit(){ alert("Hello"); }, 12000);

Comment: For the syntax part of setTiemout first argument, yes.
Can't say about the other parts of your code, as i didn't understand what such a code would do (without the HTML part at least), nor what your are trying to achieve in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this;

```
setTimeout(yourSubmitFunction, 3000)

function yourSubmitFunction() {
    //do whatever you want to do you can define submit here
}
```

You can call setTimeout in a loop, like for each element in your array which has your "post****" variables.

Comment: how to do setTimeout in a loop in my case?